# One testcase per class or all testcases in one class

Tags: language-agnostic, testing

I want to ask you about your testcases hierarchy.

Dou you have one testcase per class or all testcases in one class?

I'm using python with selenium  but I think it doesn't matter. All testcases are for the same website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey.
You can put all test cases in one class, and when it grows (like 2KLOC :P ) then you really should re-factor it to separate classes.
Or you can put in into separate classes just to separate different groups of test cases.

So: 'It depends', 'whatever suits you', 'what your specific setup needs', 'the simplest thing that works', 'it is not that really important how you do it, as long as you do it', etc.. :)